# ld: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 _OBJC_CLASS_$

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I run the pod to install - I face this issue. I have done the following steps to solve it. But It didn't. Can someone please look into it.

- Deleting DerivedData
- Installing Pods ( Deleting Poids Folder Or Disintegrate )
- *No Common Blocks* value is set to *NO*
- Tried removing *-ObjC* flag in *Other Linker Flags* but It shows *$(inherited)* only

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Globals in:

```
/Users/taimur.ajmal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Objects-normal/x86_64/Globals.o

/Users/Pods/Tune/Tune.framework/Tune(Globals.o)
```

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Globals in:

```
/Users/taimur.ajmal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Objects-normal/x86_64/Globals.o

/Users/Pods/Tune/Tune.framework/Tune(Globals.o)
```

> ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)